# Down arrow key triggers coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(0) : "\"

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, linux-ubuntu, wsl2

I am using NVIM 0.9.0 stable release with Conqueror of Completion which I installed recently.

I am used to using the arrow keys in insert mode for quick navigation between two lines. After installing `coc`, whenever I press the down or up arrow keys, I get

```
coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(0) : "\"
```

and

```
"
coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(0) : "\
```

repectively. I have not set any special Key Bindings related to `coc` except:

```
nnoremap <C-l> :call CocActionAsync('jumpDefinition')<CR>
```

`:verbose map <Up>` does not return anything, However this is the output of `:verbose map! <Up>`:

```
i  <Up>        *@pumvisible() ? '<Up>' : '<C-R>=<SNR>42_FlushBuffer()<CR>coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(0) : "\<Up>"'
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-autoclose/plugin/AutoClose.vim line 471
i  <Up>        * coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(0) : "\<Up>"
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim/plugin/coc.vim line 733
```

Comment: Maybe could you share with us the mapping you define for <Down> and <Up> in insert mode? It will help to reproduce and analyse your problem.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I only have the default mapping for up and down arrow keys. Plus, I don't have a lot of mappings in my init.vim, only one related to coc, the others are for nerd tree

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Edited question

Comment: Looking at the code of [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/blob/master/plugin/AutoClose.vim) it seems that something odd is done. One way would be to replace [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/blob/master/plugin/AutoClose.vim) by a maintained plugin (e.g. `:CocInstall coc-pairs`) another would be to fix `AutoClose.vim` at line 472 :-/

Comment: Do you still have something open in the question? How can we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) is not compatible with the [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) pre-mapping of <kbd>Up</kbd>. [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose)  assumes that the pre-mapping of <kbd>Up</kbd> is either nothing or a fixed string. But the [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) has an expression mapping for <kbd>Up</kbd> and this is not expected by [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose).

I suggest you to replace the unmaintained [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) by a maintained solution for auto pairs (since you are already using coc maybe could you use: `:CocInstall coc-pairs`)

Other maitained contender are:

- [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs)
- [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate)
- [vim-closer](https://github.com/rstacruz/vim-closer)
- [auto-pair-gentle](https://github.com/vim-scripts/auto-pairs-gentle)

Remark: Another solution is to correct the way `auto-close` reuse the mapping of `coc-nvim`. The `s:CreateExtraMaps()` of `auto-close` need to be adapted but, the plugin not-being maintained, this is not very motivating :-|.

Remark: Another attempt you could do is the change the order in which [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) are declared. Since the problem come from the way [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) correct the mapping if [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) is declared after [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) it could be that it solves the problem.